# Docker compose flask-app fails to connect to ES exit with code 1

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch, flask, docker-compose

I am new to docker-compose and I was following a tutorial the aim is to make ES work with a flask app when I launch the two containers and create the network to isolate them manually everything works fine but when I tried to use docker-compose I have this strange error which looks more of a warning than the root cause of the absence of connection between ES and my flask web app :

```bash
docker-compose up
Building with native build. Learn about native build in Compose here: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-native-build/
Creating network "foodtrucks_default" with the default driver
Creating es ... done
Creating foodtrucks_web_1 ... done
Attaching to es, foodtrucks_web_1
es     | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:46,268][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:46,480][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [XZz4TuM] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root)]], net usable_space [921.1gb], net total_space [982.3gb], types [ext4]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:46,481][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [XZz4TuM] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:46,486][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [XZz4TuM] node name derived from node ID [XZz4TuMGRQmISPJ-VpaDOA]; set [node.name] to override
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:46,487][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [XZz4TuM] version[6.3.2], pid[1], build[default/tar/053779d/2018-07-20T05:20:23.451332Z], OS[Linux/5.4.0-65-generic/amd64], JVM["Oracle Corporation"/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/10.0.2/10.0.2+13]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:46,489][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [XZz4TuM] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.yFMQabHq, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -XX:UseAVX=2, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,001][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,002][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [analysis-common]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,002][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [ingest-common]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,002][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [lang-expression]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,003][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [lang-mustache]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,003][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [lang-painless]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,003][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [mapper-extras]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,004][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [parent-join]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,004][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [percolator]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,005][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [rank-eval]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,005][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [reindex]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,006][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [repository-url]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,006][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [transport-netty4]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,006][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [tribe]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,006][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [x-pack-core]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,007][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,007][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,009][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,009][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,009][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [x-pack-security]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,010][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,010][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [x-pack-upgrade]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,011][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,012][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
es     | [2021-02-25T09:26:51,012][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [XZz4TuM] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
web_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.3) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
web_1  |   RequestsDependencyWarning)
web_1  | Unable to connect to ES. Retrying in 5 secs...
web_1  | Unable to connect to ES. Retrying in 5 secs...
web_1  | Unable to connect to ES. Retrying in 5 secs...
web_1  | Out of retries. Bailing out...
foodtrucks_web_1 exited with code 1
```

the content of the flask-app container :

```py
cat flask-app/app.py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, exceptions
import os
import time
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
import sys
import requests

es = Elasticsearch(host='es')

app = Flask(__name__)

def load_data_in_es():
    """ creates an index in elasticsearch """
    url = "http://data.sfgov.org/resource/rqzj-sfat.json"
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    print("Loading data in elasticsearch ...")
    for id, truck in enumerate(data):
        res = es.index(index="sfdata", doc_type="truck", id=id, body=truck)
    print("Total trucks loaded: ", len(data))

def safe_check_index(index, retry=3):
    """ connect to ES with retry """
    if not retry:
        print("Out of retries. Bailing out...")
        sys.exit(1)
    try:
        status = es.indices.exists(index)
        return status
    except exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print("Unable to connect to ES. Retrying in 5 secs...")
        time.sleep(5)
        safe_check_index(index, retry-1)

def format_fooditems(string):
    items = [x.strip().lower() for x in string.split(":")]
    return items[1:] if items[0].find("cold truck") > -1 else items

def check_and_load_index():
    """ checks if index exits and loads the data accordingly """
    if not safe_check_index('sfdata'):
        print("Index not found...")
        load_data_in_es()

###########
### APP ###
###########
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/debug')
def test_es():
    resp = {}
    try:
        msg = es.cat.indices()
        resp["msg"] = msg
        resp["status"] = "success"
    except:
        resp["status"] = "failure"
        resp["msg"] = "Unable to reach ES"
    return jsonify(resp)

@app.route('/search')
def search():
    key = request.args.get('q')
    if not key:
        return jsonify({
            "status": "failure",
            "msg": "Please provide a query"
        })
    try:
        res = es.search(
                index="sfdata",
                body={
                    "query": {"match": {"fooditems": key}},
                    "size": 750 # max document size
              })
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({
            "status": "failure",
            "msg": "error in reaching elasticsearch"
        })
    # filtering results
    vendors = set([x["_source"]["applicant"] for x in res["hits"]["hits"]])
    temp = {v: [] for v in vendors}
    fooditems = {v: "" for v in vendors}
    for r in res["hits"]["hits"]:
        applicant = r["_source"]["applicant"]
        if "location" in r["_source"]:
            truck = {
                "hours"    : r["_source"].get("dayshours", "NA"),
                "schedule" : r["_source"].get("schedule", "NA"),
                "address"  : r["_source"].get("address", "NA"),
                "location" : r["_source"]["location"]
            }
            fooditems[applicant] = r["_source"]["fooditems"]
            temp[applicant].append(truck)

    # building up results
    results = {"trucks": []}
    for v in temp:
        results["trucks"].append({
            "name": v,
            "fooditems": format_fooditems(fooditems[v]),
            "branches": temp[v],
            "drinks": fooditems[v].find("COLD TRUCK") > -1
        })
    hits = len(results["trucks"])
    locations = sum([len(r["branches"]) for r in results["trucks"]])

    return jsonify({
        "trucks": results["trucks"],
        "hits": hits,
        "locations": locations,
        "status": "success"
    })

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ENVIRONMENT_DEBUG = os.environ.get("DEBUG", False)
    check_and_load_index()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=ENVIRONMENT_DEBUG)
```

the content of the docker compose

```yaml
# cat docker-compose.yml 
version: "3"
services:
  es:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
    container_name: es
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  web:
    image: ducker1989/foodtrucks-web
    command: python3 app.py
    depends_on:
      - es
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ./flask-app:/opt/flask-app
volumes:
    esdata1:
      driver: local
```

my docker-compose version is  :

```bash
# docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.28.2, build 67630359
```

What am I missing any advice, indication is greatly welcomed

Comment: In `safe_check_index`, what is the actual exception?

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by safe_check_index ?

Comment: The second function in your source code.

Comment: the exception happens when the containerized app fails to connect to ES on the 9200 port that's the only exception

Comment: what i don't understand is that when I execute the commands manually everything works but once I use the docker-compose it fails although I can see clearly that the two containers are created and running plus the network also

Comment: If you look at the exception object `e`, it should have a message like "connection refused" or "no such host" or something Elasticsearch-specific.  From your answer I gather it must have been "connection refused", but the content of the exception will point much more specifically at what needs to be addressed.

Comment: @DavidMaze Firstly thank you for taking the time to comment I see better now /what you mean anyway as I said in my answer the sleep time was the problem now everything works as expected I do not know who marked down my question if it is you could you please enlighten me what is wrong with it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229237/discussion-between-jinja-dude-and-david-maze).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335038/docker-container-app-doesnt-run-while-using-wait-for-script-in-docker-compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well finally I found what is wrong it is the time.sleep(5) ES takes sometime to launch which makes the web up quit before all the services of ES are up which results in the exit of the app changing it to 15 did the trick :

```
except exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print("Unable to connect to ES. Retrying in 15 secs...")
    time.sleep(15)
    safe_check_index(index, retry-1)
```