# Docker container app doesn't run while using wait-for script in docker-compose

Tags: python, linux, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

Short explanation about my issue.

We're talking about a two-tier structure in docker-compose.

2 containers running in 1 docker-compose on the same network between them.

Since I need my ElasticSearch container to run first, I used a script on my app container to let ES run first and then, run the app.

It seems to look like the ES is running properly, and the app is shutting down.

Maybe is part of the exercise to check the app code and I already check to see any missing details over the file.

Please have a look at my docker file, docker-compose, and the app file.

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services: 
    app:
        image: food15
        restart: always
        container_name: foodtruck_app
        entrypoint: sh -c './wait-for.sh es:foodtruck_app -- python3 app.py'
        ports:
            - "8085:5000"
        environment: 
            - "discovery.type=single-node"
            - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
        networks: 
            - elastic
        depends_on: 
            - es

    es:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.0
        container_name: es
        ports: 
            - "9200:9200"
            - "9300:9300"
        volumes:
            - "data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
        networks: 
            - elastic

networks: 
    elastic:
        driver: bridge

volumes: 
    data:
        external: true
```

Dockerfile of building app:

```
FROM alpine:3.14.0
# Expose port 5000 of app (not sure)
EXPOSE 5000

# Install all build tools
RUN apk add --update nodejs npm
RUN apk add --update npm
RUN apk update
RUN apk add py3-pip
RUN apk add python3


# Move files to container area
COPY /project /app
# Move specific file to container area
COPY wait-for.sh /app/flask-app/
# Switch directory in container to the app.py file
WORKDIR /app/flask-app/
RUN ls
# Giving +x to file
RUN chmod +x wait-for.sh

# Important for future maybe
# RUN apk add -q update && apk add -qy install netcat


# Build source files
RUN npm install
# another command similar but different to 'npm install'
RUN npm run build
# Install dependencies of app with pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Run app
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "app.py" ]
```

App file:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, exceptions
import os
import time
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
import sys
import requests

es = Elasticsearch(host='es')

app = Flask(__name__)

def load_data_in_es():
    """ creates an index in elasticsearch """
    url = "http://data.sfgov.org/resource/rqzj-sfat.json"
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    print("Loading data in elasticsearch ...")
    for id, truck in enumerate(data):
        res = es.index(index="sfdata", doc_type="truck", id=id, body=truck)
    print("Total trucks loaded: ", len(data))

def safe_check_index(index, retry=3):
    """ connect to ES with retry """
    if not retry:
        print("Out of retries. Bailing out...")
        sys.exit(1)
    try:
        status = es.indices.exists(index)
        return status
    except exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print("Unable to connect to ES. Retrying in 5 secs...")
        time.sleep(5)
        safe_check_index(index, retry-1)

def format_fooditems(string):
    items = [x.strip().lower() for x in string.split(":")]
    return items[1:] if items[0].find("cold truck") > -1 else items

def check_and_load_index():
    """ checks if index exits and loads the data accordingly """
    if not safe_check_index('sfdata'):
        print("Index not found...")
        load_data_in_es()

###########
### APP ###
###########
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/debug')
def test_es():
    resp = {}
    try:
        msg = es.cat.indices()
        resp["msg"] = msg
        resp["status"] = "success"
    except:
        resp["status"] = "failure"
        resp["msg"] = "Unable to reach ES"
    return jsonify(resp)

@app.route('/search')
def search():
    key = request.args.get('q')
    if not key:
        return jsonify({
            "status": "failure",
            "msg": "Please provide a query"
        })
    try:
        res = es.search(
                index="sfdata",
                body={
                    "query": {"match": {"fooditems": key}},
                    "size": 750 # max document size
              })
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({
            "status": "failure",
            "msg": "error in reaching elasticsearch"
        })
    # filtering results
    vendors = set([x["_source"]["applicant"] for x in res["hits"]["hits"]])
    temp = {v: [] for v in vendors}
    fooditems = {v: "" for v in vendors}
    for r in res["hits"]["hits"]:
        applicant = r["_source"]["applicant"]
        if "location" in r["_source"]:
            truck = {
                "hours"    : r["_source"].get("dayshours", "NA"),
                "schedule" : r["_source"].get("schedule", "NA"),
                "address"  : r["_source"].get("address", "NA"),
                "location" : r["_source"]["location"]
            }
            fooditems[applicant] = r["_source"]["fooditems"]
            temp[applicant].append(truck)

    # building up results
    results = {"trucks": []}
    for v in temp:
        results["trucks"].append({
            "name": v,
            "fooditems": format_fooditems(fooditems[v]),
            "branches": temp[v],
            "drinks": fooditems[v].find("COLD TRUCK") > -1
        })
    hits = len(results["trucks"])
    locations = sum([len(r["branches"]) for r in results["trucks"]])

    return jsonify({
        "trucks": results["trucks"],
        "hits": hits,
        "locations": locations,
        "status": "success"
    })

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ENVIRONMENT_DEBUG = os.environ.get("DEBUG", False)
    check_and_load_index()
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=ENVIRONMENT_DEBUG)
```

Log output when i tried to run docker compose up:

```
Creating network "foodtrucks_elastic" with driver "bridge"
Creating es ... done
Creating foodtruck_app ... done
Attaching to es, foodtruck_app
es     | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:35,339][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:35,397][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [xXNsHIz] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/nvme0n1p7)]], net usable_space [64gb], net total_space [95.6gb], types [ext4]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:35,397][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [xXNsHIz] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:35,399][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [xXNsHIz] node name derived from node ID [xXNsHIz2R0yircwGvdQwdg]; set [node.name] to override
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:35,399][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [xXNsHIz] version[6.3.0], pid[1], build[default/tar/424e937/2018-06-11T23:38:03.357887Z], OS[Linux/5.8.0-59-generic/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/10.0.1/10.0.1+10]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:35,399][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [xXNsHIz] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.WpeOollh, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,241][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,241][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [analysis-common]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,241][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [ingest-common]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,242][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [lang-expression]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,242][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [lang-mustache]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,242][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [lang-painless]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,242][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [mapper-extras]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,242][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [parent-join]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,242][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [percolator]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,242][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [rank-eval]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,242][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [reindex]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,242][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [repository-url]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [transport-netty4]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [tribe]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [x-pack-core]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,244][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [x-pack-security]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,244][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,244][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [x-pack-upgrade]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,244][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,245][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:37,245][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xXNsHIz] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:39,831][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [xXNsHIz] parsed [0] roles from file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/roles.yml]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:40,251][INFO ][o.e.x.m.j.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [controller/118] [Main.cc@109] controller (64 bit): Version 6.3.0 (Build 0f0a34c67965d7) Copyright (c) 2018 Elasticsearch BV
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:40,832][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [xXNsHIz] using discovery type [zen]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:41,578][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [xXNsHIz] initialized
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:41,578][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [xXNsHIz] starting ...
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:41,780][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [xXNsHIz] publish_address {172.22.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:41,803][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [xXNsHIz] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:44,977][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [xXNsHIz] zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)[, ], reason: new_master {xXNsHIz}{xXNsHIz2R0yircwGvdQwdg}{SbE9aquQQZWhJLtoqyjzqQ}{172.22.0.2}{172.22.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=16491986944, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:44,982][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [xXNsHIz] new_master {xXNsHIz}{xXNsHIz2R0yircwGvdQwdg}{SbE9aquQQZWhJLtoqyjzqQ}{172.22.0.2}{172.22.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=16491986944, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}, reason: apply cluster state (from master [master {xXNsHIz}{xXNsHIz2R0yircwGvdQwdg}{SbE9aquQQZWhJLtoqyjzqQ}{172.22.0.2}{172.22.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=16491986944, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true} committed version [1] source [zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)[, ]]])
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:45,005][INFO ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [xXNsHIz] publish_address {172.22.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:45,006][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [xXNsHIz] started
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:45,356][WARN ][o.e.x.s.a.s.m.NativeRoleMappingStore] [xXNsHIz] Failed to clear cache for realms [[]]
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:45,383][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [xXNsHIz] license [749628c8-ccca-4874-a425-2206b74dc27c] mode [basic] - valid
es     | [2021-07-11T09:38:45,405][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [xXNsHIz] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
foodtruck_app | Operation timed out
foodtruck_app | Operation timed out
foodtruck_app exited with code 1
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What is in the `wait-for.sh` script?  (What does it do with the `es:foodtruck_app` option?)

Comment: @DavidMaze I used this script from github to launch one container before the second one, please check this link: `https://github.com/eficode/wait-for`, about what you said `es:foodtruck_app` is how you use this script (check github) `./wait-for host:port|url`

Comment: @DavidMaze So basically I connected the host which is the `es` container to `foodtruck_app` which holds the port to the app container. All of this to launch es before app. Maybe the problem is here?

Comment: In that invocation I'd expect "port" to be the usual Elasticsearch port 9200, not the name of the calling container; `wait-for es:9200 -- ...`.

Comment: @DavidMaze Now it looks like it works and showing this: `foodtruck_app |  * Running on http://localhost:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` still explorer showing nothing. I tried with many ports to see what appers.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried to reach the `index.html` page to load the website. Using this: `http://127.0.0.1:8085/index.html` nothing works. I also change in the app ip on the buttom between `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` not sure what is the currect host to the app from my machine.

Comment: @DavidMaze It works!
Apparently, I tried `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` in the app file in the bottom of the file to edit the host path. nothing works. Then, I switched back to `0.0.0.0`, and boom everything works. I would happy to get some help to really understand what I just did here with your help David. Really appreciate.